# return to page on which login button was pressed - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, authentication, laravel-5

I am trying to implement a UX guideline: let an user return to location where he clicked `/login` button.

My idea is to use

```
       $request->session()->put('get_back_to_here', URL::back());
```

or put an extra field in the login form  `/login`, with value `URL::back()`.

### My problem

1. where is the logic responsible for processing form - it is not in the `Auth/AuthController.php`.
2. Is there any other way to do this?
3. I have the same task with social logins. Should I use a cookie?
   I followed this tutorial to implement SUCCESSFULLY the social login functions:
   http://goodheads.io/2015/08/24/using-facebook-authentication-for-login-in-laravel-5/
   Modyfying the

   return redirect()->route('home');

so that it would read a cookie would be simple. But would that be a best practice?

Answer (score 0):

The logic should really go to the AppController or at an event listener. I assume It's generic functionality that will be used in many controllers.

From what I understand, you will have a login button in many pages like a header or a footer so you wish to store the place where he clicked at . look at laravel redirects and routing https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-controller-actions
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#accessing-the-current-route
You can use the Route::current() when the login button is pressed to get the current route and store it in the Session. there is nothing wrong with using the session for something like this.

Alternatively, you can bind an event to listen to the login action (look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#defining-events) and dynamically create a button that appears after login and sticks to the header or footer of your page that upon click will redirect to the Route::current() url that was stored upon login action.

Hope it helps to give you an idea

Comment: Well, I know my general idea. I am just uncapable of implementing due to poor php programming skills.
As far as I understand, I need to find and clone the auth mechanism delivered by Laravel out-of-the-box. I guess I need to create my routes too. As I have used the hackathon sterter kit, I have routes defined in routes.php, but they are overruled by sth **hidden** in the L5.2 code.